# How can I declare a global array in C first and then initialize its size later?

Tags: c

I have an array that I want to have in global scope. Its size however is determined during runtime, so I can't initialize it where I define it.

How can I declare it in global scope and assign its size in the `main` function?

Comment: Make a global pointer and allocate its memory in main()

Comment: A global array has a static size. This is required by the language, full stop. But you can have a global pointer that you later assign to a dynamic (malloc-ed) array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your comment *I guess there is no way of having the array on the stack*, I wanted to show you that the pointer and the pointed object can have any storage. If the C implementation support Variable Length Array, you can make your global pointer point to a VLA:

```
int *glob_array;

int main() {
    ...
    // obtain the size of the array in sz:
    size_t sz;
    sz = ...
    int arr[sz];

    glob_arr = arr;      // a global pointer to a VLA
    ...
}
```

As `arr` is defined in `main` (and not in a sub block) it will only reach its end of life when the program will end. Yet it has automatic storage, meaning that for most implementation it will reside in the stack.

Disclaimer: the actual allocation is an implementation detail, and the compiler could allocate it in a heap if it wants to.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdlib.h>   // for malloc

int *globalarray;

int main()
{
  ...
  globalarray = malloc(thesizeyouwant * sizeof(*globalarray));
  ...
  globalarray[0] = foo;
  ...
  free(globalarray);
}
```

Comment: Alright, so I guess there is no way of having the array on the stack. Thanks. One question:
What is behind the expression *globalarray? The *-operator follows the pointer right? But when the expression is evaluated the pointer was not (explicitly) assigned to any memory location.

Comment: @David it reads `int* globalarray` i.e. `int*` a pointer to int. You might interested in this tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm

Comment: @David You are confused it seems. `so I guess there is no way of having the array on the stack`. Make your mind, you want it global or local?

Comment: Ah ok thanks. But if `*globalarray` evaluates to `int*`, what would the expression `globalarray` evaluate to?

Comment: @David it is a name. The type is `int*`. When you use it `globalarray` it's the address of the first element.

Comment: @TonyTannous has the scope of a variable something to do with wether its allocated on the stack or heap? I thought if I e.g. declared a global variable `struct Foo glob;` it would be on the stack. No?

Comment: @David there are multiple storage durations. static (global) dynamic (heap) and local (stack). google it for a better understanding

Comment: @TonyTannous so just to clarify my confusion: `sizeof(*globalarray)` and `sizeof(globalarray)` both evaluate to the size of an `int*`, because `*globalarray` is the variable wich is of type `int*` and `globalarray` is a pointer (without type?) to an address, so its `int*` too?

Comment: @David not quite: the type of `*globalarray` is `int` therefore `sizeof(*globalarray)` is the same as `sizeof(int)`. The type of `globalarray` is `int*` (pointer to `int`) and `sizeof(globalarray)` is the size of a pointer. Don't mix up `int` and `int*`, latter is a _pointer_ to `int` and the size of a pointer is not necessarily the same as the size of an `int`.

Comment: @David you need to read the chapter about memory management. To clear your confusion, `*globalarray` is the first element, you are dereferencing the pointer. The size will be size of int. The other `sizeof(globalarray)` is the size of the pointer.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yes, that's what I thought, but then I still don't get what `*globalarray` evaluates to if it was never (explicitly) assigned. What does it point to? What does the function `sizeof(*globalarray)` get in this case?

Comment: @Jabberwocky and why is `sizeof(*globalarray)` the same as `sizeof(int)`? `int` is a type while `*globalarray` is a **value** of type `int`. No?

Comment: Because `sizeof` is a special operator, you can use it for the size of a type or for the size of a value.